# PHP wrong ecoding JSON to file

Tags: php, html, json

I am solving this issue. I got and array after preg_split from PHP. What I want is to converted into JSON. I tried almost everything and still the code is badly written, seems to be not encode at all. Here is part of my code.

```
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $split = preg_split('/(\/>)/', $_POST['content']);
    $json = json_encode($split, true);
    file_put_contents("newfile.json", $json);
    $message = "<xmp>".$content."</xmp>";  
}
```

code after encode looks something like this:

```
["\u003Cpath d=\"m34.511 143.4v3.0302l54.101-0.63086v-2.078z\" points=\"34.510773,146.42924 88.611514,145.79838 88.611514,143.72037 34.510773,143.39908 \" fill=\"#353564\"","\r\n\u003Cpath d=\"m34.511 146.43 78.119 2.1017 56.193-2.4552-80.211-0.27738z\" points=\"112.6299,148.53093 168.82266,146.07576 88.611514,145.79838 34.510773,146.42924 \" fill=\"#afafde\"","\r\n\u003Cpath d=\"m88.612 143.72 80.211-1.5957v3.9511l-80.211-0.27738z\" points=\"168.82266,142.1247 168.82266,146.07576 88.611514,145.79838 88.611514,143.72037 \" fill=\"#e9e9ff\"","\r\n\u003Cpath d=\"m34.511 143.4 78.119-4.6834 56.193 3.409-80.211 1.5957z\" points=\"112.6299,138.71569 168.82266,142.1247 88.611514,143.72037 34.510773,143.39908 \" fill=\"#4d4d9f\"","\r\n\u003Cpath d=\"m112.63 138.72v9.8152l56.193-2.4552v-3.9511z\" points=\"112.6299,148.53093 168.82266,146.07576 168.82266,142.1247 112.6299,138.71569 \" fill=\"#d7d7ff\"","\r\n\u003Cpath d=\"m34.511 143.4 78.119-4.6834v9.8152l-78.119-2.1017z\" points=\"112.6299,138.71569 112.6299,148.53093 34.510773,146.42924 34.510773,143.39908 \" fill=\"#8686bf\"","\r\n\u003Cpath d=\"m81.675 70.138v77.656l19.018-0.51308v-65.842z\" points=\"81.675079,147.79421 100.6926,147.28113 100.6926,81.438896 81.675079,70.138158 \" fill=\"#353564\"","\r\n\u003Cpath d=\"m81.675 147.79 44.367 1.2456 17.465-1.0002-42.814-0.75847z\" points=\"126.04182,149.03978 143.50669,148.0396 100.6926,147.28113 81.675079,147.79421 \" fill=\"#afafde\"","\r\n\u003Cpath d=\"m100.69 81.439 42.814-27.133v93.734l-42.814-0.75847z\" points=\"143.50669,54.305844 143.50669,148.0396 100.6926,147.28113 100.6926,81.438896 \" fill=\"#e9e9ff\"","\r\n\u003Cpath d=\"m81.675 70.138 44.367-40.744 17.465 24.912-42.814 27.133z\" points=\"126.04182,29.393818 143.50669,54.305844 100.6926,81.438896 81.675079,70.138158 \" fill=\"#4d4d9f\"","\r\n\u003Cpath d=\"m126.04 29.394v119.65l17.465-1.0002v-93.734z\" points=\"126.04182,149.03978 143.50669,148.0396 143.50669,54.305844 126.04182,29.393818 \" fill=\"#f6ff17\"","\r\n\u003Cpath d=\"m81.675 70.138 44.367-40.744v119.65l-44.367-1.2456z\" points=\"126.04182,29.393818 126.04182,149.03978 81.675079,147.79421 81.675079,70.138158 \" fill=\"#8686bf\"",""]
```

original array is as this:

```
Array ( [0] => <path d="m34.511 143.4v3.0302l54.101-0.63086v-2.078z" points="34.510773,146.42924 88.611514,145.79838 88.611514,143.72037 34.510773,143.39908 " fill="#353564" [1] => <path d="m34.511 146.43 78.119 2.1017 56.193-2.4552-80.211-0.27738z" points="112.6299,148.53093 168.82266,146.07576 88.611514,145.79838 34.510773,146.42924 " fill="#afafde" [2] => <path d="m88.612 143.72 80.211-1.5957v3.9511l-80.211-0.27738z" points="168.82266,142.1247 168.82266,146.07576 88.611514,145.79838 88.611514,143.72037 " fill="#e9e9ff" [3] => <path d="m34.511 143.4 78.119-4.6834 56.193 3.409-80.211 1.5957z" points="112.6299,138.71569 168.82266,142.1247 88.611514,143.72037 34.510773,143.39908 " fill="#4d4d9f" [4] => <path d="m112.63 138.72v9.8152l56.193-2.4552v-3.9511z" points="112.6299,148.53093 168.82266,146.07576 168.82266,142.1247 112.6299,138.71569 " fill="#d7d7ff" [5] => <path d="m34.511 143.4 78.119-4.6834v9.8152l-78.119-2.1017z" points="112.6299,138.71569 112.6299,148.53093 34.510773,146.42924 34.510773,143.39908 " fill="#8686bf" [6] => <path d="m81.675 70.138v77.656l19.018-0.51308v-65.842z" points="81.675079,147.79421 100.6926,147.28113 100.6926,81.438896 81.675079,70.138158 " fill="#353564" [7] => <path d="m81.675 147.79 44.367 1.2456 17.465-1.0002-42.814-0.75847z" points="126.04182,149.03978 143.50669,148.0396 100.6926,147.28113 81.675079,147.79421 " fill="#afafde" [8] => <path d="m100.69 81.439 42.814-27.133v93.734l-42.814-0.75847z" points="143.50669,54.305844 143.50669,148.0396 100.6926,147.28113 100.6926,81.438896 " fill="#e9e9ff" [9] => <path d="m81.675 70.138 44.367-40.744 17.465 24.912-42.814 27.133z" points="126.04182,29.393818 143.50669,54.305844 100.6926,81.438896 81.675079,70.138158 " fill="#4d4d9f" [10] => <path d="m126.04 29.394v119.65l17.465-1.0002v-93.734z" points="126.04182,149.03978 143.50669,148.0396 143.50669,54.305844 126.04182,29.393818 " fill="#f6ff17" [11] => <path d="m81.675 70.138 44.367-40.744v119.65l-44.367-1.2456z" points="126.04182,29.393818 126.04182,149.03978 81.675079,147.79421 81.675079,70.138158 " fill="#8686bf" [12] => )
```

Please can you little push me where I am making mistake?

Comment: What is your desired result/output?

Comment: anyhow normal JSON.. do not matter .. I thik is bad encode language with UTF-8 , I am not sure.. desired result can be [ 0: { path.....}.. mainly it will contain all what JSON have :)

Comment: What's wrong with it?  Looks fine?

Comment: Update your question with a desirable output, your code may not reflect your desired intentions, see my answer. I think you may be wanting to break down the XML properties as JSON properties, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

One issue appears to be caused by [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) not accepting a `true` argument. Instead it uses option flags in that position, which in your case is parsed as a `1` by the lexer and is the same as the `JSON_HEX_TAG` option flag. Resulting in `\u003C` instead of `<` in your output.

To resolve the issue you should use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option flags, as you are not performing additional escaping on the `POST` value.

Example: https://3v4l.org/BsH5l

```
print_r(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Results in:

```
[
    "<path d=\"m34.511 143.4v3.0302l54.101-0.63086v-2.078z\" points=\"34.510773,146.42924 88.611514,145.79838 88.611514,143.72037 34.510773,143.39908 \" fill=\"#353564\"",
    "<path d=\"m81.675 70.138 44.367-40.744v119.65l-44.367-1.2456z\" points=\"126.04182,29.393818 126.04182,149.03978 81.675079,147.79421 81.675079,70.138158 \" fill=\"#8686bf\""
]
```

I believe you may be wanting to translate the XML properties as JSON properties, but your code does not indicate as such.

---

Assuming you are wanting to convert the `$_POST['content']` containing an XML string into a JSON array of objects.

One method to achieve the desired results is to use the [`DOMDOcument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the post content string into the desired data format.

Example: https://3v4l.org/hOepd

```
if (isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])) {
    //first make the post content valid XML
    $xml = '<xmp>' . $_POST['content'] . '</xmp>';

    //use the DOMDOcument class to load the XML string 
    //add your own error handling
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($xml);
    $array = []; //placeholder to store the data

    //iterate over the <path/> tag elements
    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('path') as $node) {
        $attributes = [];
        //convert the attributes into an associative array by attribute name
        foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute) {
            $attributes[$attribute->name] = $attribute->value;
        }
        //store the tag and attributes into array
        $array[] = (object) [
            $node->tagName => $attributes
        ];
    }

    $json = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/newfile.json', $json);
}
```

XML String:

```
<path d="m34.511 143.4v3.0302l54.101-0.63086v-2.078z" points="34.510773,146.42924 88.611514,145.79838 88.611514,143.72037 34.510773,143.39908 " fill="#353564"/>
<path d="m34.511 146.43 78.119 2.1017 56.193-2.4552-80.211-0.27738z" points="112.6299,148.53093 168.82266,146.07576 88.611514,145.79838 34.510773,146.42924 " fill="#afafde"/>
```

JSON Results:

```
[
    {
        "path": {
            "d": "m34.511 143.4v3.0302l54.101-0.63086v-2.078z",
            "points": "34.510773,146.42924 88.611514,145.79838 88.611514,143.72037 34.510773,143.39908",
            "fill": "#353564"
        }
    },
    {
        "path": {
            "d": "m34.511 146.43 78.119 2.1017 56.193-2.4552-80.211-0.27738z",
            "points": "112.6299,148.53093 168.82266,146.07576 88.611514,145.79838 34.510773,146.42924",
            "fill": "#afafde"
        }
    }
]
```

If you update your question with your desired results, I can provide a more thorough answer.